# Undefined reference to function declared in header file C

Tags: c, gcc

I have looked at a lot of posts with this error but none of them seem to have the simple case that I have.

**libsuyash.h**:

```
#ifndef libsuyash_h
#define libsuyash_h

#include<stdlib.h>

const int ENDEH = 1;
#define is_littleendian() ( (*(char*)&ENDEH) != 0 )

typedef unsigned char* ucp;
typedef u_int32_t uint32t;

unsigned char* xdatahex(unsigned char*);
int myfun(char, int);

#endif
```

**libsuyash.c**:

```
#include<string.h>
#include "libsuyash.h"

unsigned char* xdatahex(unsigned char* string) {

    if(string == NULL) 
       return NULL;

    size_t slength = strlen(string);
    if((slength % 2) != 0) // must be even
       return NULL;

    size_t dlength = slength / 2;

    ucp data = malloc(dlength);
    memset(data, 0, dlength);

    size_t index = 0;
    while (index < slength) {
        char c = string[index];
        int value = 0;
        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
          value = (c - '0');
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') 
          value = (10 + (c - 'A'));
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
          value = (10 + (c - 'a'));
        else {
          free(data);
          return NULL;
        }

        data[(index/2)] += value << (((index + 1) % 2) * 4);

        index++;
    }

    return data;
}

int myfun(char a, int b) {
    return 69;
}
```

Following is the simple function where I am using it:
**clarglen.c**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "libsuyash.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    myfun('g', 8);

    ucp samplehexstr = "cafebabe";
    ucp hextodata = xdatahex(samplehexstr);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%c,", *(hextodata++));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I simply run: `gcc clarglen.c` (or sometimes with `-o <outputfile>`) and I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGDTY5N.o: in function `main':
clarglen.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `myfun'
/usr/bin/ld: clarglen.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `xdatahex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am clueless about what else I am missing. **All files are in the same directory.**

Comment: Where do you compile or link `libsuyash.c`?

Comment: I was told since it's in the same directory I don't need to..

Comment: Whoever told you is wrong.

Comment: just add libsuyash.c to the compile command

Comment: Suppose you have three files in the same directory with different names (previous versions) and they all contain those two functions. How would the linker know which one to use without a specific instruction?

Comment: But I have only included the one .h file which has only one .c file of the same name. Formaly, this seems to be sufficient information, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: That only tells the compiler which .h files to include in the compilation. It doesn't tell the linker which of the compiler's output files to link, and if you haven't told the compiler to compile `libsuyash.c` it won't. Why should it? You told it to include `libsuyash.h` in the compilation of `clarglen.c`. And there does not have to be a one-to-one correspondance between the .h and the .c file names.

Comment: ...for example, you might have a header file `defs.h` which contains your types and macros (but there is no file `defs.c`) which is included by files `one.c`, `two.c` and `three.c`. How would the compiler guess that you need to compile and link those .c file from the header name? Would you expect it to complain that it can't find `defs.c`?